# JSP: Creating Graph

Tags: java, jsp, graphics, charts, graph

What would be the simplest way to create some graphical representations of the usage of electricity by month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to produce an image from your data, and then display the image in the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution for me was outputting numerical arrays in the backend and displaying with [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) (google javascript library). All you need to do is generate your series of points 
(e.g. something like ([1,0], [2,1.1], [3,1.4],[4, ] ... ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) or a Google Chart API Java wrapper. I wrote one: [charts4j](http://charts4j.googlecode.com/).